# Why am I getting a different result when I store in a variable my PS script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I made a Powershell script that does a foreach on a strings array and collects only some info of them.
This is the code:

```
begin {
    $IMAGELIST = @(
    "IMAGE Srv01 something something something Srv01_999888777 something"
    "FRAG 1 something something"
    "FRAG 2 something something"
    )
}   

process {
    foreach ($LINE in $IMAGELIST) {
        if ($LINE.StartsWith("IMAGE")) {
            $IMAGELINE = $LINE.split()
            $BKP_OBJ = [pscustomobject]@{
                Server=$IMAGELINE[1]
                Id=$IMAGELINE[5]
            }
        }

        elseif ($LINE.StartsWith("FRAG")) {
            $FRAGLINE = $LINE.split()
            $BKP_OBJ | Add-Member -Force @{
                CopyNumber = $FRAGLINE[1]
            }
            Write-Output -InputObject $BKP_OBJ
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the script I have an output with two objects with different CopyNumber values (expected result):

```
PS C:\Users\db> .\BkpScript.ps1
Server            : Srv01
Id                : Srv01_999888777
CopyNumber        : 1

Server            : Srv01
Id                : Srv01_999888777
CopyNumber        : 2
```

If I try to store the output in a variable, I have the same CopyNumber (not expected result):

```
PS C:\Users\db> $myvar = .\BkpScript.ps1
PS C:\Users\db> $myvar
Server            : Srv01
Id                : Srv01_999888777
CopyNumber        : 2

Server            : Srv01
Id                : Srv01_999888777
CopyNumber        : 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us some more about the problem you try to solve with this script? It contains a lot of stuff to make it ready for pipelining, for example, but I do not understand why. What dou you want as a result? A List of objects, a string or just output on the terminal?

Comment: The root cause for your problem is the fact, that you create an object in case 1 and after that you are altering it in case 2 instead of making copies of it. Therefore all "snapshots" of your object will be the same pointers that point to the last altered version.

Comment: Normally the $IMAGELIST is an array of strings given by an external command output.
The external command gives three or more lines for every unique record (First line is always IMAGE, others are more than one FRAG)
For every unique record, I need to create an object with some info from IMAGE string and some info from FRAG strings.
@Thomas what you said sounds sensible to me, but I  can't completely understand.
How should I change the script in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will create a new object whenever it shall be output/piped:

```
begin {
    $IMAGELIST = @(
    "IMAGE Srv01 something something something Srv01_999888777 something"
    "FRAG 1 something something"
    "FRAG 2 something something"
    )
}   

process {
    $Server = ""
    $Id = ""
    $CopyNumber = 0
    foreach ($LINE in $IMAGELIST) {
        if ($LINE.StartsWith("IMAGE")) {
            $IMAGELINE = $LINE.split()
            $Server=$IMAGELINE[1]
            $Id=$IMAGELINE[5]
        } elseif ($LINE.StartsWith("FRAG")) {
            $FRAGLINE = $LINE.split()
            $CopyNumber = $FRAGLINE[1]
            Select-Object @{n='Server'; e={$Server}}, @{n='Id'; e={$Id}}, @{n='CopyNumber'; e={$CopyNumber}} -InputObject ''
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like you expect in your question:

> ```
> PS C:\Users\db\Desktop> .\test.ps1
>
> Server Id              CopyNumber
> ------ --              ----------
> Srv01  Srv01_999888777 1
> Srv01  Srv01_999888777 2
>
>
> PS C:\Users\db\Desktop> $myvar = .\test.ps1
> PS C:\Users\db\Desktop> $myvar
>
> Server Id              CopyNumber
> ------ --              ----------
> Srv01  Srv01_999888777 1
> Srv01  Srv01_999888777 2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this?

```
begin {
    $BKP_OBJ = $null
    $IMAGELIST = @(
    "IMAGE Srv01 something something something Srv01_999888777 something",
    "FRAG 1 something something",
    "FRAG 2 something something"
    )
}   

process {
    $Ximglist = @()
    $Xfrglist = @()
    foreach ($LINE in $IMAGELIST) {
        if ($LINE.StartsWith("IMAGE")) {
            $Ximglist += $LINE
        }
        elseif ($LINE.StartsWith("FRAG")) {
            $Xfrglist += $LINE
        }
    }
    foreach ($Ximg in $Ximglist) {
        $Xfrglist | % {($_.split())[1]} | % {$BKP_OBJ = [pscustomobject]@{
                    Server= ($Ximg.Split())[1]
                    Id= ($Ximg.Split())[5]
                    CopyNumber=$_
                }; 
                Write-Output $BKP_OBJ}
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could save the `$BKP_OBJ` to a variable (say `$ARR_BKP_OBJ`) that you can use later on. By doing`$ARR_BKP_OBJ = @()` and `$ARR_BKP_OBJ += $BKP_OBJ`.

Comment: I tried to add $BKP_OBJ to an array first, but when I try to store the output of the script into $myvar variable I get the same unexpected result
Consider that IMAGE and FRAG strings are a set of informations  that I cannot process in two separate arrays in a second time, because I can have more than one set of info.
Eg.
  "IMAGE Srv01 something something something Srv01_999888777 something"
  "FRAG 1 something something"
  "FRAG 2 something something"
  "IMAGE Srv02 something something something Srv02_456734231 something"
  "FRAG 1 something something"
  "FRAG 2 something something"

Comment: Sounds like you want to be using nested `foreach`'s? Or (like my solution) a `Foreach-Object` (=`%`) in a `foreach` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You're only making one object, that you modify and output twice.  The assignment statement makes it complete first, before any output is shown.  The pointer is the same to both outputs.  (.\BkpScript) would do the same thing.

```
cat myscript.ps1

$a = [pscustomobject]@{name='Joe'}
$a
$a.name = 'John'
$a


./myscript      

name
----
Joe
John


(./myscript)  # or ./myscript | sort

name
----
John
John
```